# Applying the click event to a LI inside a UL instead of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, frameworks, html-lists

I really need your help.

How can I, move from a button click (rename) to initiate my rename function to a click event inside a UL LI. I'd like to move the `$('button').click(fn);` to the LI whos value is 'rename'. As I am moving away from the button, and creating a separate right-click menu, it is important that the click event to fire my rename function come from the LI click.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29objbzx/1/

A pic of the expected outcome is attached:

[image]

The code in question:

```
$(function(){


    $('#refdocs_list li').click(fn);

    $('button').click(fn);

    function fn(e){
    var el = $('#refdocs_list li.selected');
    if(e.target.type != "button"){
            el.removeClass('selected');
            $(e.target).addClass('selected');
    }else{  
        var txt = el.text(); 
        var newEl = $("<input id='rename_refdoc'>");
        newEl.blur(function(){
            el.html(newEl.val());       
        });
        newEl.val(txt);
        el.html(newEl);  
        newEl.focus().select();
    }     
    }   
})();
```

I was thinking:

```
$('#right-click-menu li:eq(5)').click(function(e) {
    fn(e);
});
```

but it's not working either.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question? or Give us an example of an expected behavior.

Comment: To re-rephrase it, duplicate what the button does when you click on 'rename' in the UL LI. I no longer wish to use the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Simply add the button handler to the li and change the condition to check for ID instead of button target. See below code.

**Note:** Removed `onclick` function in your HTML and added ID attribute as `renameLI`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/29objbzx/2/

```js
    $('#renameLI').click(fn);
    $('#refdocs_list li').click(fn);

    function fn(e) {
      var el = $('#refdocs_list li.selected');
      if (e.target.id != "renameLI") {
        el.removeClass('selected');
        $(e.target).addClass('selected');
      } else {
        var txt = el.text();
        var newEl = $("<input id='rename_refdoc'>");
        newEl.blur(function() {
          el.html(newEl.val());
        });
        newEl.val(txt);
        el.html(newEl);
        newEl.focus().select();
      }
    }
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
#refdocs {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
#refdocs_main {
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  width: 179px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#refdocs_main:hover {
  border-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
#refdocs_container {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  height: 20px;
}
#refdocs_wrapper {
  height: 116px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#refdocs_list {
  width: 100%;
}
#refdocs_list ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#refdocs_list li {
  cursor: default;
  padding: 2px;
}
#refdocs_main:hover,
#refdocs_main:hover #refdocs_container {
  border-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
.selected {
  background: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}
#rename_refdoc {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">rename</button>
<div id="refdocs_main">
  <div id="refdocs_container">
    <input type="text" id="refdocs" />
  </div>
  <div id="refdocs_wrapper">
    <div id="refdocs_list">
      <ul>
        <li>red</li>
        <li>green</li>
        <li>blue</li>
        <li>yellow</li>
        <li>orange</li>
        <li>purple</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="right-click-menu">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="refdocs_copy()">Copy</li>
    <li onclick="refdocs_paste()">Paste</li>
    <li onclick="refdocs_add()">Add</li>
    <li onclick="refdocs_delete()">Cut</li>
    <li onclick="refdocs_clear()">Clear list</li>
    <li id="renameLI">Rename</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:** Updated your code to use the same function. See below,

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7pya31w7/2/)**

1. Removed the else as we going to do the button function on click of `LI`
2. Get the selected element if nothing was selected at first click

**Code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#refdocs_list li').click(function (e) {
        fn(e);
    });
    $('button').click(fn);

    function fn(e) {
        var el = $('#refdocs_list li.selected');
        if (e.target.type != "button") {
            el.removeClass('selected');
            $(e.target).addClass('selected');
        }
        el = $('#refdocs_list li.selected');
        var txt = el.text();
        var newEl = $("<input id='rename_refdoc'>");
        newEl.blur(function () {
            el.html(newEl.val());
        });
        newEl.val(txt);
        el.html(newEl);
        newEl.focus().select();

    }
});
```

---

If I understood correctly, you want to rename the list on clicking the `LI` like how you click on rename button.

```
$('#refdocs_list li').click(function (e) {
    fn(e);
    $('button').click();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7pya31w7/)

Comment: Almost there. See new pic attached! Please remove the button. My function needs to trigger when the LI "Rename" is clicked in the list whos div id is: "right-click-menu"

Comment: Yes! that's it. Super cool, marvelously awesome work! Yay I now have hair left on my head. Thanks so much.